# Is it possible to bind a sharepoint grid view to a list view(and not the original list)?

Tags: 2010, list-view, gridview

I have created a grid view which is binded to a list. I have also created a list view for this particular list with some filtered data. I want to know whether is it possible to bind the sharepoint grid view with a list view instead of binding it to a normal list?

**Update** I have used this [link](http://deepaksemwalsp.blogspot.in/2012/08/binding-data-from-sharepoint-list-to.html)

to bind my grid view to list

Comment: If i understood you question,  you have created a view in a list and you want to bind your grid to this newly created list. Please correct me if i am wrong. Could you please share how you are binding a grid view to a list view?

Comment: @404 you are right. I want to bind this grid view to the list view I have created.

Comment: Could you please share the code how you have bind the list to grid view please. so i can suggest modification within?

Comment: @404 I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update the code of `bindToGrid()` as below:

```
protected void bindToGrid()
{
    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    //SPList list = web.Lists["Employee"];
    SPView spView = web.Lists["Employee"].Views[<YOURVIEWNAME>];
    SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery(spView);
    //SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
    SPListItemCollection items = web.Lists["Employee"].GetItems(spQuery);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = bindToDataTable(items);
    grid.DataSource = dt;
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

Basically instead of fetching data from default view, we are making use of `SPQuery` to specify the view which we want to use. Replace `<YOURVIEWNAME>` in code with the name of view you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Step By step Simple tutoria is below hope this might be a help

http://sharepoint.kerenapura.com/2013/09/display-sharepoint-list-data-gridview/